# correct output for this fork concept in C

Tags: c, output, fork, atoi

So for some reason I can't get the output of this code in C, so I can only ask a few conceptual question on this code below:

1. What does `int N = atoi(argv[i]);` do? is it just define integer N
   as an array?
2. In the for loop, what does `if (-1 = fork())` mean? Is -1 means its an error or not the right loop? That means I can't create a child using fork?
3. What does the `getpid()` do in the call to the printf function?
4. And what should the right output be?

code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    int i;
    int N = atoi(argv[i]);
    printf("Create processes....\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (-1 = fork())
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("Process id  = %d\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add "And why doesn't this compile?" to your list of questions; `-1 = fork()` isn't valid C. Pretty sure that the real code has `==`

Comment: in the `int N =` line, `i` is used without being initialized. You probably want `argv[1]`, but first make sure that the argument actually exists.

Comment: it would help immensely if you were to read the man pages for the functions for which you have questions.

Comment: the posted code will not cleanly compile.  One reason is cannot assign a value to a literal in if (-1 = fork())  another reason is the parameter 'argc' is not used.  Should be checking it to assure the command line parameter was entered, before trying to use that parameter.  a third reason is in 'int N = atooi(argv[i]); the variable 'i' is not initialized to any specific value,   The compiler will raise warnings about these problems.  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  (in gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )

Comment: the posted code has the logic problem that all the child processes will continue executing the loop, so many more processes will be created than what ever number is on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the questions you have asked can be answered by just looking into the man pages. Anyway I will try to explain them.

1) `int atoi(const char *str)`
str -- This is the string representation of an integral number. This function `atoi` returns the converted integral number as an int value. If no valid conversion could be performed, it returns zero.

As for your code, i has garbage value stored in it. So the value of `atoi(argv[i]))`is unpredictable. you might want to assign a value for `i`.

2) `-1 == fork()` , (I assume you have made a syntax error in your code, and you have figured that out already)  what happens there is we check the return value of the fork() function, If check the manual, fork() is used to create a new process. If it failed to create a new process then it return -1. It would make much sense if it is written like `fork() == -1`

3) `getpid()` returns the process ID of the calling process. (This is often used by routines that generate unique temporary filenames.)

4) What do you mean by right output? have you tried run the code and got any errors? please elaborate

If you run the corrected code with a command line argument, this is what the output looks like.

```
de@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 2
Create processes....
Process id  = 25405
Process id  = 25406
Process id  = 25408
Process id  = 25407
```

Comment: ... `i` is undefined in atoi(argv[i]) ... so the code execution is very unpredicable.

Comment: Of course, I did not notice it. I will edit my answer right away, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't why I don't have linux so I can't get the output on my eclipse, can you please post the ouput in your answer above and I promise I will accept it!

Comment: Even in windows you can get MinGW to run C code. I will give you the answer. But DO NOT make it as a habit. Always have the necessary tools around you.

Comment: Thanks! can you post it? and how do you get MinGW to run, I think fork is not recognized in eclipse?

Comment: Answer is posted, I strongly recommend you to go for a virtual machine (linux). So that you can at least run & test your code.

Comment: Thank but is there anyway I can get fork to work in windows eclipse, you said I need to download MinGW? is there a site tell you how to do it?

Comment: you can obtain the man page info by googling: 'syntax for function fork in C'   This will result in several 'hits'  most of the 'hits' will have exactly the information you are looking for.

Comment: @John check this out. http://www.cprogramming.com/faq/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044654269&id=1043284392